# Error while defining a Spring component

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'd like to define a my own component by using Spring.

Below there is my code:

**MyPasswordEncoderConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.package" })
public class CryptoConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**MyPasswordEncoder**:

```
@Component
public class MyPasswordEncoder {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; // Defined in Spring Security.

    public String encode(String plainTextPassword) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(plainTextPassword);
    }

    public boolean matches(String encodedPasswordA, String encodedPasswordB) {
        return passwordEncoder.matches(encodedPasswordA, encodedPasswordB);
    }

}
```

**MyPasswordEncoderTest**:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyPasswordEncoder.class, MyPasswordEncoderConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyPasswordEncoderTest {

    @Mock
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private MyPasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPasswordMatching() {
        String plainTextPassword = "ABCdef123@@@";
        String encodedPassword = myPasswordEncoder.encode(plainTextPassword);
        assertTrue(myPasswordEncoder.matches(plainTextPassword, encodedPassword));
    }
}
```

When I run the test, it fails. Checking the result by using the standard output, the `passwordEncoder.encode(plainTextPassword);` returns a null value.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

The problem is regarding the *PasswordEncoder* interface. If I replace it with *BCryptPasswordEncoder*, the test works fine.

Comment: What do you think it should return and why?

Comment: It have to return an hash by using BCrypt algorithm.

Comment: What do you think `@Mock` does? What do you think `InjectMocks` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gather from your test code, you actually want to test the functionality of `MyPasswordEncoder`. So why use mocks? 
Why not just use @Autowired for both `PasswordEncoder` and `MyPasswordEncoder`like in the following code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyPasswordEncoder.class, MyPasswordEncoderConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyPasswordEncoderTest {

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        private MyPasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder;

        @Test
        public void testPasswordMatching() {
            String plainTextPassword = "ABCdef123@@@";
            String encodedPassword = myPasswordEncoder.encode(plainTextPassword);
            assertTrue(myPasswordEncoder.matches(plainTextPassword, encodedPassword));
        }
    }
```

If you do not want to write a spring integration test but a simple unit test and do not want to refactor your code, you could write the following:

```
public class MyPasswordEncoderTest {

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    private MyPasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder = new MyPasswordEncoder();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myPasswordEncoder, "passwordEncoder", passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPasswordMatching() {
        String plainTextPassword = "ABCdef123@@@";
        String encodedPassword = myPasswordEncoder.encode(plainTextPassword);
        assertTrue(myPasswordEncoder.matches(plainTextPassword, encodedPassword));
    }
}
```

An even better solution (which ditches the use of Spring ReflectionTestUtils) is to refactor MyPasswordEncoder like so:

```
@Component
public class MyPasswordEncoder {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; // Defined in Spring Security.

    @Autowired
    public MyPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    public String encode(String plainTextPassword) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(plainTextPassword);
    }

    public boolean matches(String encodedPasswordA, String encodedPasswordB) {
        return passwordEncoder.matches(encodedPasswordA, encodedPasswordB);
    }

}
```

Then the unit test would become:

```
public class MyPasswordEncoderTest {

    private MyPasswordEncoder myPasswordEncoder = new MyPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

    @Test
    public void testPasswordMatching() {
        String plainTextPassword = "ABCdef123@@@";
        String encodedPassword = myPasswordEncoder.encode(plainTextPassword);
        assertTrue(myPasswordEncoder.matches(plainTextPassword, encodedPassword));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that because of `@InjectMocks`, the actual `PasswordEncoder` that is being injected is the `@Mock`

```
@Mock
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

not the one in your `@Configuration` class. (Actually, both are injected, but the mock is injected last, so that's the one that is used.) You can verify this with (if the field was visible).

```
System.out.println(MyPasswordEncoder.passwordEncoder.getClass());
```

would print something like

```
class com.spring.PasswordEncoder$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$7d70b580
// pay attention to               ^        this part       ^
```

Mocks are typically implemented to return `null` for reference types, `0` for numerical primitives, and `false` for boolean.